# How to save app on back button press

Tags: android

How can I store the state of my app when back button is pressed.

When back button is pressed only `onPause()` is called but not `onSaveInstanceState` where we can store our data in outState bundle.

One answer may be `sharedPreference` but my problem is it will store only int and not `intArray` as bundles does.

Is there any way to explicitly call `onSaveInstanceState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user 600027... Even if you were able to call onSaveInstanceState the bundle would not be persisted and I do not believe it would be available after a hard kill. You could write a method to convert an array of ints to set of strings and then persist the data by calling putStringSet() and then write a method to covert a set of strings to an array of ints.

JAL

Answer (score 1):

You can do normal saving in `Activity#onDestroy()`.

I think the intention behind `onCreate(Bundle)`, `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` is to provide for a chance for you to save state before being killed in the background. The app should then recover and appear to the user as if nothing happened.

On a back button press the user is in some sense "finished" with the activity. The amount of data that should be saved is different. Yes, it would be a good idea to save your state in `SharedPreferences` in this case.