# popupwindow : window get leaked on back button

Tags: android

I am creating `popupwindow` as below,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(TimerGameActivity.this);
        TextView textView = new TextView(TimerGameActivity.this);
        textView.setText("Quit? Score will be lost....");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(linearLayout, 200, 100,true);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10)
}
```

But I am facing problem as below. It doesn't let me show popupwindow and destroys activity when i press back button, it gives me the following error:

```
04-18 15:04:55.457: E/WindowManager(590): Activity has leaked window android.widget.LinearLayout@44f88be8 that was originally added here
```

Help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove :

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious to get an exception there, because when you are pressing Back Button `super.onBackPressed();` is fired and your Activity is going to get finish and at the same time you are trying to show a PopupWindow. So, there is no UI for PopupWindow to be shown. So, just remove `super.onBackPressed();` and try to show `PopupWindow` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`onBackPressed()` will going to destroy your activity and at the same time you doing UI operation with reference of the same activity, so how it will work?

reference [Which actions does the back button/back key on Android trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290019/which-actions-does-the-back-button-on-android-trigger)